# how can we apply aspect oriented programming on a particular line of java class ?

Tags: aspectj

```
How can we apply aop on the last line of main method ?
```

Below is a test class for call by value in java. I have been asked in one interview to apply Aspect oriented programming on last line of the class. Is it possible to apply AOP on a particular line of any java class, if yes then please give some example code.

```
public class TestCallByValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st = new Student("Sanjeev", 1);

        changeName(st);

        System.out.println(st.getName());//apply aop on this line to stop printing sysout
    }

    public static void changeName(Student st) {
        st = new Student("Rajeev", 2);
        st.setName("Amit");
    }

}

class Student {
    String name;
    Integer id;

    public Student(String name, Integer id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What can be applied on a particular line of java code is called a **joinpoint**

This [link](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-joinPoints.html) lists the possible joinpoints you can set in your code, with aspectj. As you can see, only constructor call, method call, field initialization, etc. can be defined as joinpoints

The only way is to apply a pointcut on `System.out#println`. You could as well encapsulate `System.out.println(st.getName());` in a dedicated method

Comment: This doesn't answer my question as encapsulating in method won't help in answering actual problem to apply aop on a particular line. Can it be done using load time weaving using aspectj ?

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ doesn't operate on source code, it operates on the semantic structure of Java programs. As such, it doesn't have a concept of "lines". The interviewer meant that you should prevent a particular method call from happening, and told you where that method call is, in this particular case it's the last statement of the `main` method.

This statement is located in `TestCallByValue.main()` method and invokes `println()` on `System.out`, which is a `PrintStream`. While we cannot indicate to AspectJ that we want to prevent only the "last" statement from executing, we can narrow this down to

> *method calls to the `println` method of the `PrintStream` class, accepting a `String` and returning void, within the code contained in the `TestCallByValue.main()` method that accepts an array of Strings and returns void*

To prevent the method call from happening, you will need an *around advice* which doesn't call `proceed()`. We can also check whether the target of the method call is actually `System.out`, so we prevent only `System.out.println(String)`, not `println(String)` calls on other instances of `PrintStream`.

The above can be achieved with the following aspect:

```java
aspect DummyAspect {

    pointcut printlnStatementInMain(): withincode(void TestCallByValue.main(String[])) 
        && call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(String));

    void around(): printlnStatementInMain() {
        if (thisJoinPoint.getTarget() != System.out) {
            proceed();
        }
    }

}
```